# Can css block to insert space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a form where I just can insert a space on inputs. In the textarea I can't (and I need).

As you can see, insert space on textarea works perfectly.

```html
<form action="/#wpcf7-f519-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="519">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="pt_BR">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f519-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0">
</div>
<p><label> Name: </label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p><label> E-mail: </label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p><label> Message: </label> <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span></p>
<p><label>  </label> <span>  </span><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

But in my form, I cant.
I'm using Contact Form 7 in wordpress, and I already tried to swith the textarea, but didn't worked.

I take a screenshot showing the css of textarea because I didn't put any JS that points to any textarea (I couldn't see anything that could  block the spaces).
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution? Because blocking inputs is really a job for JavaScript. You've tagged JavaScript in your question, so is a JavaScript solution acceptable?

Comment: Or even HTML5 with built-in form validation?

Comment: Yes, any solution is acceptable. I just need to be able to insert space in textarea.

Comment: Wait... What's your problem here? What do you want/expect to happen and what does happen?

Comment: For some reason I can't insert space on textarea. And I need to be able to insert.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but my guess is that maybe there are listeners attached to your form element that prevents default behavior in case of space key press. Something like:

```
var textArea = document.querySelector("textarea[name='your-message']");
textArea.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    // space character
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

You could try to unbind all listeners to the textarea element.
Using javascript only:

```
var textArea = document.querySelector("textarea[name='your-message']");
var clone = textArea.cloneNode();
while (textArea.firstChild) {
  clone.appendChild(textArea.lastChild);
}
textArea.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, textArea);
```

Using jQuery:

```
var textArea = $("textarea[name='your-message']");
textArea.unbind();
textArea.off();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried all options but I still can't insert space. It's the only thing that I need to remove my website of "under construction"...

Comment: Is there anything in your console? Can you paste in spaces?

Comment: Yes I can past spaces. Please, help me.